# Is preaching recommended or mandatory to a temple priest?

Tags: scripture, temple, priests

Every temple in India has at least one priest. The act of preaching scriptures a recommended act or mandatory act for him?

Comment: Preaching where? in temples?

Comment: Yeah........  @AkshayS

Comment: temples are not for that purpose....nor temples are for prayers.!!!

Comment: @AkshayS i understand its not the exclusive place of prayers as are church or mosque etc.Do you mean it in that sense?

Comment: @Pratimaputra temples are abode of deities but temples are constructed in a place where specific planetary rays fall and the Yantra, stones they use it are according to those specific purpose. So each temples construction has its own purpose and even if one doesnt pray, if they enter the temple itself is enough because its an energy point. In Tamil we say that as  NAVA RATHINA STONE (9 stones related to nine planets). EX: Pazhani Muruga temple is constructed where Mars planet rays is falling.

Comment: i understand its not the exclusive place of prayers as are church or mosque etc.Do you mean it in that sense? - Yes I meant in that sense because author talked of preaching in temples!

Comment: @Pratimaputra I think you must also be knowing that each temple has particular Virksha - the tree....related to specific Nakshatra. So temples are ultimately has own purpose to it.

Comment: @Pratimaputra - In Tamil yantras, these are explained. We have here 9 stones with related to 9 planets, 9 type of Mulikai, leaves for 9 planets, 9 Dhaniyam (wheat) for food related to 9 planets etc.... slowly these knowledge are dimnishing. If we go to villages in TN, its still in practice but in cities only to certain extent these are known.

Comment: @AkshayS thats really great.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91447/discussion-between-akshay-s-and-pratimaputra).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Smritis, the temple priests are in fact considered fallen/degraded. Probably because they earn through the act of worshipping.

> Manu Smriti 3.152. Physicians, **temple-priests**, sellers of meat, and
>   those who subsist by shop-keeping **must be avoided at sacrifices
>   offered to the gods and to the manes.**
>
> 3.180 (Food) given to a seller of Soma becomes ordure, (that given) to a physician pus and blood, **but (that presented) to a temple-priest is
>   lost,** and (that given) to a usurer finds no place (in the world of the
>   gods).

Alternate translation from [Wisdomlib.org](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199961.html):

> सोमविक्रयिणे विष्ठा भिषजे पूयशोणितम् ।
>  नष्टं देवलके
>   दत्तमप्रतिष्ठं तु वार्धुषौ ॥ १८० ॥
>
> somavikrayiṇe viṣṭhā bhiṣaje pūyaśoṇitam |
>  naṣṭaṃ devalake
>   dattamapratiṣṭhaṃ tu vārdhuṣau || 180 ||
>
> What is given to the Soma-seller becomes ordure; to the physician, pus
>   and blood; that to the temple-attendant becomes lost; and that to the
>   usurer has no place.—(180)

The link also gives a similar verse from Mahabharata which is as follows:

> Mahābhārata (13.90, 13, 14).—‘What is given to the Soma-seller and to
>   the physician becomes pus and blood; what is given to the
>   temple-servant perishes; it is neither here nor there.’

So, it is certainly not their responsibility to teach scriptures.

Comment: For 3.180 you can read the Sanskrit verse from here: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199961.html @Pratimaputra the word used is Devala

Comment: @Pratimaputra Actually the translation I have used has food in it .. this wisdomlib translation has what is ..

Comment: Yes that's why they have added it in brackets .. if I now change it to what is .. then it will be a mixture of two translations .. @Pratimaputra

Comment: I have now added both the translations .. @Pratimaputra